# why it shows promise pending with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Why the output shows "Promise {  }" when it expected to shows "Bienvenue"

```
const translate = require('google-translate-api');

async function translateSentence(sentence, languebase, languagetranslation) {
    var sentenceTranslated = await translate(
        sentence,
        { from: languebase, to: languagetranslation });

    return sentenceTranslated.text;
}

var Translatedtext = translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr");
console.log(Translatedtext);
```

UPDATE:

I'm trying to return the translated data into JSON here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 data = new Object();
    data.Translatedtext = Translatedtext;

  var string = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

The out shows as `{ Translatedtext: {} }` and I expected something like `{ Translatedtext: {Bienvenue} }`

Comment: We would need to see what you are doing in translate. It should be returning a Promise.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: No, we don't. `async` functions **always** return a promise.

Comment: The promise could be pending because `translate` never gets resolved, so seeing it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `translate` is returning a promise, we could make an async function and wait for `translateSentence` to do it's thing then add the text to the object.

This would be done like this:

```
async function performOperations(){
    let Translatedtext = await translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr")
    data = new Object();
    data.Translatedtext = Translatedtext;

    var string = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(JSON.parse(string));
}

performOperations()
```

What you are doing is checking the object before it has finished processing the request to the google api. So your data is more than likely getting to its location, its just that you're looking at the object too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Because `async` functions return promises, so `Translatedtext` is a reference to a promise, and when you dump it out, you see the details of that promise, including the fact that it's pending.

If you meant to get the *result*, you'd have to `await` it (or use `then`):

```
var Translatedtext = await translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr");
// ------------------^
console.log(Translatedtext);
```

(handling the exception if it rejects), or

```
translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr")
    .then(Translatedtext => {
        console.log(Translatedtext);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle the fact an error occurred
    });
```

Note that to use `await`, you'd have to be in an `async` function.

Comment: Will I be able to store the `Translatedtext` into Json?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is written with `async/await` it does not mean that you can get the value in not an `async` function. Your function just returns the Promise. Anyway you need to write like

```
translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr").then(text => console.log(text));
```

or call this function in the another `async` function

```
async anotherFunction() {
   const text = await translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr");
   console.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`translateSentence` is defined as `async`, thus it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

This means you need to wait for the promise resolve/reject before being able to access the result:

```
translateSentence("Welcome", "en", "fr")
  .then(Translatedtext => {
    var data = { Translatedtext };
    var string = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(JSON.parse(string)); 
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err);
```